# Android: Dropbox API Error

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I am getting following Authentication error while trying to login in Dropbox api. Heres the message:
Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}

I am using Google API Level8 of Android platform 2.2.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unistalling and re-installing your version of Android?
ive been looking through various peoples posts and this seems to be the remedy for quite a few Error message Problems. If this does not work try again on a different system with the same software versions etc. and see if the problem still arises. If so contact a direct email address for Android related problems? Im sure there are a few email adresses but choosing one is down to you :)

hope this helps :)